# How to setup .ssh/config for git on non-standard port

Tags: linux, ssh, git, openssh

I know something similar has been asked multiple times, but I wasn't able to find the right solution for my case.

I have a custom git repository accessible via ssh on a non-standard port; URL is something like:

```
git clone ssh://myname@my.repo.host:12345/path/to/repo/project.git
```

private key for that repo is in `~/.ssh/myname.prv`.

I am trying to get access the repo without passwords, but I'm failing.

My current `~/.ssh/config` has a stanza:

```
Host git
    HostName my.repo.host
    Port 12345
    User myname
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myname.prv
```

... but git still asks for a PW.

What am I missing?

Note: both server and client are fairly recent Linux machines and I'm working at the command line, if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the use of the `~/.ssh/config` file.  You have:

```
Host git
    HostName my.repo.host
    ...
```

However, the first line `Host git` defines the name (alias) (i.e. `git`) of the host to connect to and that which you specify on the command line to either `ssh` or `git`.  That is, you could now `ssh` to your git remote server via

```
ssh git
```

... and you can clone the git repo using your 'custom' hostname using:

```
git clone ssh://git/path/to/repo/project.git
```

Note that your remote will now list `origin` as exactly that address, which is dependent upon your `ssh` config file.

Alternatively, if you wish to retain the `my.repo.host` in the address of your git remote, change your `~/.ssh/config` to read:

```
Host my.repo.host
    #HostName my.repo.host
    Port 12345
    User myname
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myname.prv
```

( NOTE: The `HostName` directive is redundant in this case, so I left it commented out. )

With that, you could simplify your remote and clone using:

```
git clone ssh://my.repo.host/path/to/repo/project.git
```